# Transferring Sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list

Now im Working on Development or test server and im about to finish the branding and everything on Sharepoint enterprise server 2013 all my work done in /Style Library
, _catalogs/masterpage/ and Page Layout
Now i want to Transfer all that to a production server

i wanna know the most trusted and the safest way to do it and if there any way to transfer also custom lists ?

also if theres any way to extract all files in /Style Library/ Folder from sharepoint designer in case if i'll have to do the transfer manually ?

Comment: Is SharePoint Designer the only tool available to you?

Comment: I work only with it but i've full access over the both servers i can use any tool but i dont know anything can help me even i tried to create design package in design manager it ended with unknow kind of error "Error generating solution files in temporary directory."

Comment: Can you build a SharePoint solution (.wsp) using Visual Studio? That way you can first build, test, and deploy on your Dev server and then once the wsp is finished, just redeploy that to your PROD.

Comment: @Water, that was going to be my next question :-)

Comment: I tried that once with simple solution and the feature has been added to the site collection and then i got Error Activating the feature and i couldnt know why there wasnt any details for the error just sharepoint ther these words "something went wrong" general error 

i was following that tut
http://sharepoint.rackspace.com/Documents/CreatingWSP_VS2013.pdf

Comment: i really want to know how to do that hows that workflow going how to test every single change in real time

Comment: I think in that workflow we can use Sass or even grunt to make more usable, more clean scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a create a SharePoint Project in Visual Studio and deploy your customizations using a WSP. In order to deploy the master pages, custom css files and page layouts, you need to create a modules. Following example shows the xml code to deploy the master page to master page gallery:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MasterPageModule" List="116" Url="_catalogs/Masterpage">
    <File Url="mycustommaster.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Path="MasterPageModule\mycustommaster.master" />    
  </Module>  
</Elements>
```

Following example show the xml code to deploy custom page layout to master page gallery:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="ClientSitePageLayouts" Url="_catalogs/Masterpage">
      <File Path="ClientSitePageLayouts\ClientCommonPage.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Url="ClientCommonPage.aspx">
          <Property Name="Title" Value="Client Site Common Page Layout" />
          <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
          <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/CustomPageLayout.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/CustomPageLayout.png" />
          <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_articlepage_name;;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D;#" />
      </File>    
</Module>
</Elements>
```

And following xml code shows how to deploy css files to  Style library:

```
<Module Name="Styles" Url="style Library">
<File Path="Styles\newstyle.css" Url="newstyle.css" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
</Module>
```

In order to use the master page in the site, you need to create a Site Scoped feature and code similar to this in Feature Activated Event.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        string serverRelativeURL = web.ServerRelativeUrl;
        web.CustomMasterUrl = string.Format("{0}/_catalogs/masterpage/mycustommaster.master", serverRelativeURL == "/" ? "" : serverRelativeURL);       
        web.Update();
    }
}
```

Following is the sample code to create a page from Page Layout in a Web Scoped Feature Activated Event:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;       
    PublishingWeb pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
    PageLayout clientPageLayout = GetPageLayoutByName("ClientCommonPage.aspx", pubWeb);
    CreatePage(pubWeb, "ClientDocuments.aspx", "Client Documents", clientPageLayout, false)
}

private PageLayout GetPageLayoutByName(string name, PublishingWeb pubWeb)
{
    PageLayout[] layouts = pubWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts();

    var matches = from l in layouts
                  where l.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                  select l;
    if (matches.Count<PageLayout>() > 0)
        return matches.First<PageLayout>();
    else
        return null;
}

public SPFile CreatePage(PublishingWeb web, string pageName, string pageTitle, PageLayout layout, bool isLandingPage)
{
    PublishingPageCollection pages = web.GetPublishingPages();
    var p = pages.ToList().Find(x => x.Name.Equals(pageName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (p == null)
    {
        PublishingPage page = web.GetPublishingPages().Add(pageName, layout);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageTitle))
        {
            page.Title = pageTitle;
            page.Update();
        }

        SPFile pageFile = page.ListItem.File;

        if (isLandingPage)
        {
            web.DefaultPage = pageFile;
            web.Update();
        }

        return pageFile;
    }
    else
        return p.ListItem.File;
}
```

Comment: And how to create page from page layout on subsite ?

Comment: And assign it as home

Comment: How to test all that without deploying ?

Comment: You can test in the test server. If you don't want to impact the original work, you can create new web application or site collection and test there.

Comment: Good it worth another try